# Navigation onclick of flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I am not able to navigate to diffrent screen onClicking the flatlist item

[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkv1d.png)

i tried your suggestion .. gave error [as suggested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqypi.png) gave this error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZdTu.jpg)

Here i am attaching my App.js where i have created stack [001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP40p.png)...[002](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO6Sn.png)..[003](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8ANc.png)...[004](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjAHH.png)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
const onclick item (key) => {
    switch (key) {

    case "Complain"
      navigation.navigate('Complainscreen') //Navigate
     break;

    case "Call Us":
     break;

    default:
     }
    }
```

Comment: It gave an error I have attached  a screenshot

Comment: Remove 'this.' in 'this.onclick item(item.key)}' , in function component no need 'this' for calling function.

Comment: I did the error is gone but it's not navigating to other screen

Comment: This code is fine. Can you show the code where you create the navigation stack

Comment: Change the 'Complainscreen' to 'Complain' .in  navigation.navigate('Complainscreen') .

Answer (score 0):

Your initial screenshot doesn't work because you're also using `this.` on the onClick

```
const onclick item (key) => {
  switch (key) {
    case "Complain"
      navigation.navigate('Complainscreen') //Navigate
      break;
   case "Call Us":
     break;
   default:
   }
}
```

Then on your TouchableOpacity's onPress

`onPress={(item) => onclick_item(item.key)}`

Comment: i tried this its not giving any error but it is also not navigating to complain screen

Comment: what exactly is in your navigation prop?

Comment: I am trying do is in my support screen I want to make a complaint flat list so when I click on the item it navigate me to complain screen where I can submit a complain